# Indices at the left of a tensor in mathematical physics/differential geometry?

Tags: differential-geometry, notation, mathematical-physics, tensors

I am a mathematician and I am reading a paper in mathematical physics and I found the following notation:

> Let $Y$ be a two–form on $M$ such that $$\nabla({}_iY_j)_k = 0.$$

Here, $\nabla$ is supposed to be a connection. I have never seen that notation in mathematics (lower-left indices)? Could someone help me understand it?

Comment: Perhaps part of the confusion is that the parentheses are probably part of the subscripts, namely, $\nabla_{(i} Y_{j)k} = 0$; this formatting makes it a little clearer that the $i$ is attached to the $\nabla$ rather than $Y$ alone.

Comment: Incidentally, the parentheses have a meaning here: they indicate symmetrisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, $i$ is, if you like, the index corresponding to the direction of the covariant derivative. More precisely, for, say, a $1$-form $\eta$,
$\nabla_i \eta_j$ is the abstract index notation for denotes the $2$-tensor $\nabla \eta$ defined by $$(\nabla \eta)(X, Y) := (\nabla_X \eta)(Y).$$ Indeed, in abstract index notation this quantity is $\nabla_i \eta_j X^i Y^j$.

Perhaps you're more familiar with the notation $\eta_{j, i}$, where $_,$ denotes the covariant derivative. (This is quite compact, but it is sometimes less convenient, especially when more than connection is in play.)

Comment: Why does the $k$ is outside the parenthesis and the $j$ inside in the case of a two-form instead of a 1-form?

Comment: The parentheses denote symmetrization over the indices inside them. So, $$\nabla_{(i} Y_{j)k} = \frac{1}{2} (\nabla_i Y_{jk} + \nabla_j Y_{ik})$$. (NB the factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ is not universal, but it has the benefit that if $\omega_{ij}$ is already symmetric in $i, j$ then $\omega_{(ij)} = \omega_{ij}$.)

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there an equivalent notation for antisymmetrisation then?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, you denote antisymmetrization with brackets, as in $\omega_{[ij]}$. Occasionally you'll want to (anti)symmetrize over nonadjacent indices, in which case one can enclose the skipped indices with pipes: $\omega_{(i|j|k)}$ means symmetrize over $i$ and $k$ (but not $j$). One can use this notation across indices of different tensors, too, as in $(\alpha \wedge \beta)_{ab} = 2 \alpha_{[a} \beta_{b]}$.